# Delete '0' & 'n/a' in Excel using java

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

Is there any possibility to delete the cell when the vlookup output is 0 & n/a ?

I have a code that updates cells with values that are matching basically I have added vlookup in my Java code. It returns matching values in the cell & remaining would be either '0' and 'n/a'. I wanted to remove the '0' & 'n/a' using Java can any one please let me know if this can be done.

Comment: Use The Worksheet Function `If Error` for `#N/A` and If condition for `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Just `Vlookup` in your code use this:

`If(IfError(VLookup(....),0) = 0,"",VLookup(....))`